# Mongodb conditional query search under an array

Tags: regex, mongodb, search

I have a data where an array is there. Under that array Many array of objects is there. I am mentioning the raw data so that anyone guess the structure

```
{
 _id: ObjectId(dfs45sd54fgds4gsd54gs5),
 content: [
 {
  str: "Hey",
  isDelete: false 
 },
 {
  str: "world",
  isDelete: true
 }
]
}
```

So I want to search any string that match and I have top search under an array.

So my query is like this:

```
let searchTerm = req.body.key;
db.collection.find(
 {
  'content.str': {
    $regex: `.*\\b${searchTerm}\\b.*`,
    $options: 'i',
   }
 }
)
```

So this will return the data. Now for some reason I have to search the data if `isDelete: false`.

Right now it returns the data whether isDelete is true/false because I have not mentioned the conditon.

Can anyone help me out regarding this to get the data through condition. I want this to Mongodb Query only.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: You can use lookahead assertion in regex. Example - (world).*\s+(?=isDelete: false). So first regex looks for world and when it finds it then it starts looking for isDelete: false and then it returns a match only if condition satisfies or else it wont result in a match

Comment: @rootkonda thanks for your response, I tried this but not works

Comment: Can you paste here what you tried ?

Comment: let searchTerm = `${req.body.key}.*\s+(?=isDelete: false)`;
db.collection.find(
 {
  'content.str': {
    $regex: `.*\\b${searchTerm}\\b.*`,
    $options: 'i',
   }
 }
)

Answer (score 1):

The [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator matches documents that contain an array field with at least one element that matches all the specified query criteria,

```
db.collection.find({
  content: {
    $elemMatch: {
      isDelete: true,
      str: {
        $regex: `.*\\b${searchTerm}\\b.*`,
        $options: "i"
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  "content.$": 1
})
```

Working Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/VkdWMnYtGA3

Comment: @Aks Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not.

Comment: Hey there, your code is working but it fetches only 1 object, but I want it to find all matches data as a search result.

Comment: @Tushar you can use `$filter` operator in projection, see the example [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kIwrPTP5_sa)

Comment: it's working. thanks for giving me your time. I think you have deep knowledge of MongoDB. great

Answer (score 0):

You can add another condition there as belo

```
db.test2.find({
  $and: [
    {
      "content.str": {
        $regex: "hey",
        $options: "i",
        
      }
    },
    {
      "content.isDelete": false
    }
  ]
},
{
    'content.$':1 //Projection - to get only matching array element
})
```

Comment: I tried this but it not working because this search is running under array. If it like straight entry (Without nested structure) then It works. I tried this

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by straight entry?

Comment: Like normal key and value (Normal JSON Structure).
Anyways I again tried this but this will return the entry whose isDelete: true value which I don't want on response as I assume that this entry is remove from DB

Comment: @Gibbs I'm excited, how does this positional operator works in projection?

Comment: I tried but its like same case What i mentioned on question. I return the main _id on projection. So if that keyword is deleted then response return the empty array as not data found on Showing on Frontend. 
I tried your and condition and projection also but not works. I am also surprised why this things not happend

Comment: @Gibbs I forgot to say thanks as you provide me some inputs atleast. No matter whether the query will solve or not. Sorry for not mentioning on initial response

Comment: @Aks is my understanding correct? You have an array of object. Each object contains str and is Delete. You need to match a term on str and false is Delete you are looking for.

Comment: Suppose content array have 10 objects. On 8th object str: "USA", isDelete: false. By this value if Anyone search then Main Object_id will return. Suppose if 8th Object isDelete: true. Then it will not come on result. I need the _id of the document. By user query I have to return the main Object (Mongodb Entry) not array of object

Comment: OK, 8th object? How do you fix which object it is.

Comment: @Gibbs, just informing you, look into this https://mongoplayground.net/p/7XNU8K4v5_Y , what if `"content.isDelete": true`, is it correct output?

Comment: @turvishal as per my earlier comment and my understanding it looks correct. U couldn't understand What's missing.